# Unclear definition of open sets in proof of Regular Lindelof space is normal

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, separation-axioms

I found the proof of **Regular and Lindelof spaces are normal** here https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m54x12/public_html/m54hwsolns9.pdf

and  I can't understand the last part of the proof:

$$U=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty U_n'$$ and $$V=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty V_n'$$
are the desired open sets. **Why?**

Ins't enough  $A\subset\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty U_n$ and $B\subset\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty V_n$?

Why to subtract the 
$\bigcup_{i=1}^n \overline U_i$ and $\bigcup_{i=1}^n \overline V_i$ to $ U_n$ and $ V_n$, respectively?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}\overline{V_{i}}$ is closed, and so $U_{n}-\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}\overline{V_{i}}$ is open. If it were subtracted with $V_{i}$ instead of $\overline{V_{i}}$, the whole $U_{n}'$ is not necessarily open.

Comment: How do you know that $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}\overline{V_{i}}\subset U_n$?

Comment: Why the whole $U_n'$ wouldn't  be necessarily open? $U_n$ is open.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are open, then $A-B$ is not necessarily open. Rather, if $A$ is open and $F$ is closed, then $A-F$ is open.

Comment: So is this $U_{n}-\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}\overline{V_{i}}$ just to get $U_n'$ open?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: And why precisely the finite union of $\overline V_i$?

Comment: That is by construction, perhaps you should ask why $U$ and $V$ are such desired open sets. The reasoning goes like this: For $a\in A$, since $\{U_{n}\}$ is an open cover of $A$, then $a\in U_{n}$ for some $n$. But $a\notin X-A$, so $a\notin\overline{V_{i}}$ for any $i$, so $a\in U_{n}'$.

Comment: I see, so $A\subset U_n'$. And why to take the union so that $A\subset\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty U_n'$?

Comment: It is not that $A\subseteq U_{n}'$. Rather, it is for each $a\in A$, there is a corresponding $U_{n}'$ such that $a\in U_{n}'$. So to cover $A$, take the union of all those $U_{n}'$.